# Grammar spec resolving Shift/Reduce conflicts

Tags: bison, context-free-grammar, shift-reduce-conflict, jison

I'm using Jison (Bison) to create a simple markup language.  I'm clearly new to this, but slight variations are working very well.  I just don't understand the source of the S/R conflict.

It doesn't seem matter that 'Text' is returned by two lexer actions (with different Start Conditions) and I like this because it seems to allow the grammar to have fewer rules and because the error messages to the user are consistent.  I've tried making the 'Text' rule common regardless of context and I've also tried giving each token a different name, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the S/R Conflicts when it's all together.

The parser is SUPPOSED to create a json-object with plain-text, sub-arrays, and various special nodes.

Specification:

```
/* lexical grammar */
%lex

%s bracketed

%%

<bracketed>(\\.|[^\\\,\[\]])+       { yytext = yytext.replace(/\\(.)/g, '$1'); return 'Text'; }
<INITIAL>(\\.|[^\\\[])+             { yytext = yytext.replace(/\\(.)/g, '$1'); return 'Text'; }
"["                                 { this.begin('bracketed'); return '['; }
"]"                                 { this.popState(); return ']'; }
","                                 return ','
<<EOF>>                             return 'END'

/lex

%start template

%%    

template
    : sentence END
    ;

sentence
    : /* empty */
    | sentence Text
    | sentence '[' ']'
    | sentence '[' dynamic ']'
    ;

dynamic
    : sentence
    /*| dynamic ',' sentence*/
    ;
```

Warnings:

```
Conflict in grammar: multiple actions possible when lookahead token is ] in state 5
- reduce by rule: sentence ->
- shift token (then go to state 6)

States with conflicts:
State 5
  sentence -> sentence [ .] #lookaheads= END Text [ ]
  sentence -> sentence [ .dynamic ] #lookaheads= END Text [ ]
  dynamic -> .sentence #lookaheads= ]
  sentence -> . #lookaheads= ] Text [
  sentence -> .sentence Text
  sentence -> .sentence [ ]
  sentence -> .sentence [ dynamic ]
```

Different generator algorithms have more or less trouble, but they all seem to have trouble.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The conflict comes fundamentally from these two rules:

```
sentence: sentence '[' Text ']'
        | sentence '[' sentenceList ']'
```

The reason is that after seeing a `sentence` and a `[` and looking at the next token being `Text`, the parser doesn't known whether to shift the `Text`, matching the first rule, or to treat that `Text` as the beginning of a `sentenceList` going towards matching the second rule.

Now if you had a parser generator that use 2-token lookahead, this wouldn't be a problem, but bison is LALR(1) (the 1 being one token lookahead).

There are a couple of things you could try:

- do extra lookahead in the lexer to differentiate Text-followed-by-] from Text-not-followed-by-] as two distinct tokens then rewrite the rules to use both of these tokens.
- Use bison's %glr-parser feature to use GLR parser.  This will parse the sentence both ways and later throw away the one that doesn't match
- refactor the grammar to not need 2-token lookahead.

One refactoring that works in your case would be to rewrite the `sentence` rules to make them all right-recursive instead of left-recursive:

```
sentence: /* empty */
        | Text sentence 
        | '[' ']' sentence
        | '[' Text ']' sentence
        | '[' sentenceList ']' sentence
        ;
```

This avoids having `sentence` (or any other rule that starts with `sentence` such as `sentenceList`) start with a null reduction of the `sentence: /*empty*/` rule.  So the parser can freely shift a `Text` in the problematic case deferring the reduction until it sees the next token.  It does have memory use implications, however, as it results in a parser that will essentially shift the entire input on to the parser stack and then reduce it one sentence at a time.

Another refactor you could do would be to subsume the `[Text]` and `[]` constructs into the `[sentenceList]`:

```
sentence: /* empty */
        | sentence Text 
        | sentence '[' sentenceList ']'
        ;

sentenceList: sentence
            | sentenceList ',' sentence
```

So now a `sentenceList` is one or more sentences separated by commas (instead of two or more), and in the action for the `sentence '[' sentenceList ']'` rule, you'd check the `sentenceList` to see if it was two or more sentences and act appropriately.

Comment: Great answer.  And I like the suggestion you added - that opened my mind to greater processing in those actions, hadn't thought of that.  I'm still working on making it all work though.  Do the order of rule appearances matter?

Comment: You also helped me realize that the actions aren't really necessary for Conflict resolution discussions.

Comment: In the updated grammar, you have an ambiguity because `dynamic` -> `sentence` -> `/*empty*/` means that `'[' dynamic ']'` matches the same input as `'[' ']'`.  That's a problem with my second suggested refactor, so I've fixed that.